# App Crash on Multi-tasking re-entry (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, crash, appdelegate

Been getting a strange error recently and hope to find a solution here.  On double-clicking home and immediately re-entering the app a crash occurs. I've been looking around for a solution in other SO posts but there doesn't seem to be any that come close to this strangeness.  The project uses several swift/objc open source libraries and if it is helpful I will post them here as well.  I've done everything from cleaning out the AppDelegate, DerivedData/Caches, Pods, the main controllers on re-entry(home, login, auth), and no dice :(

The system logs at the time of crash from a physical device are as follows.

```
May 22 18:53:47 iPhone-6 SpringBoard[63] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted

May 22 18:53:47 iPhone-6 SpringBoard[63] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus

May 22 18:53:47 iPhone-6 SpringBoard[63] <Warning>: UNNotificationRegistrarConnectionListener connection invalidated

May 22 18:53:47 iPhone-6 com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124
    [3269] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [0cc5/1b0b]: error: ::read ( -1, 0x16e246a38, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)

May 22 18:53:47 iPhone-6 com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124
    [3269] <Warning>: Exiting.

May 22 18:53:47 iPhone-6 gputoolsd[3265] <Notice>: schedule invalidation <DYTransport 0x13d504ba0, error: explicit invalidation (6)>

May 22 18:53:47 iPhone-6 gputoolsd[3265] <Notice>: schedule invalidation <DYTransport 0x13d50f850, error: lost transport connection (31)>
May 22 18:53:47 iPhone-6 gputoolsd[3265] <Notice>: terminating daemon 0x13d50f510

May 22 18:53:47 iPhone-6 SpringBoard[63] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.argentapp.ios[0x552c]' exited voluntarily.

May 22 18:53:47 iPhone-6 UserEventAgent[26] <Warning>: 6754616024137: id=com.argentapp.ios pid=3270, state=0
```

Edit: Back Trace from breakpoint in applicationWillTerminate below.  Also the wording of crash may be incorrect as the logs say that the app exited voluntarily upon re-entry and no lldb errors are thrown.

```
applicationWillResignActive
<UIApplication: 0x14782c3c0>
<NSUserDefaults: 0x14782ee50>
applicationWillTerminate
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x15fd47, 0x00000001000a86b0 Argent`AppDelegate.applicationWillTerminate(application=<unavailable>, self=<unavailable>) -> () + 188 at AppDelegate.swift:254, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x00000001000a86b0 Argent`AppDelegate.applicationWillTerminate(application=<unavailable>, self=<unavailable>) -> () + 188 at AppDelegate.swift:254
    frame #1: 0x00000001000a878c Argent`@objc AppDelegate.applicationWillTerminate(UIApplication) -> () + 68 at AppDelegate.swift:0
    frame #2: 0x00000001877ed240 UIKit`-[UIApplication _terminateWithStatus:] + 280
    frame #3: 0x0000000187a0bff8 UIKit`__102-[UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke2017 + 796
    frame #4: 0x0000000187a0f0c8 UIKit`_runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 292
    frame #5: 0x0000000187a1ca80 UIKit`_cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 92
    frame #6: 0x000000018774e5a4 UIKit`_afterCACommitHandler + 96
    frame #7: 0x00000001825b4728 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
    frame #8: 0x00000001825b24cc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
    frame #9: 0x00000001825b28fc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 928
    frame #10: 0x00000001824dcc50 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    frame #11: 0x0000000183dc4088 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 180
    frame #12: 0x00000001877c6088 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 204
    frame #13: 0x00000001000a8f1c Argent`main + 144 at AppDelegate.swift:41
    frame #14: 0x000000018207a8b8 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

Every other system behavior works as expected and the app functions without a hitch (pressing home and re-opening, lock screen and re-open, opening another app and re-opening, 3d touch navigation etc.).  Hope this is descriptive enough, I will try to elaborate more if it is unclear.

XCode Version 7.3

iOS Version 9.3

Swift 2.2

Comment: Can you reproduce the crash while your device is connected to the Xcode debugger?  Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: You say it crashed.  Where's the crash log?

Comment: The main issue is I can only replicate it once the app exits and re-enters (this disconnects the xcode debugger and the only breakpoint I can catch is on applicationWillTerminate) and from what I can tell no lldb error is thrown.  When I look under Window > Devices > View Device Logs it doesn't get logged as a crash but it's the only way to describe what the behavior feels like. Once I reopen the application everything works as expected unless I perform the same action.  I will post a stack trace from the breakpoint right before the behavior occurs.

Comment: @Avi attached the crash log from the device and the backtrace, any thoughts?

Comment: @Paulw11 I reproduced the crash with the debugger, also will a backtrace suffice?

Comment: There are some hits on `UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:` to do with NSNotificationObservers on deallocated objects, but your stack trace doesn't include a post notification.  It does seem to indicate that something is hanging around though; UIPopOverControllers and UIAlertControllers that are presented incorrectly also figure in searches for that method.  Are you using any crash analytics software such as CrashAlytics etc that could be capturing the underlying issue?  Basically your app is terminating itself

Comment: @Paulw11 that makes sense, I can try implementing Crashalytics tonight and that might help resolve the issue.  It is a bit frustrating to get to the root of the problem as I've tried to isolate it in many different ways to no avail (so a 3rd party library will likely help in this instance).  I'm not sure that the UIAlertViewController/UIPopOverControllers would cause an issue as the app doesn't display these UI elements on startup. I will also do a full check on all the NSNotificationObservers/NSNotificationCenter items to see if that's the issue.  Appreciate the recommendations.